# capybara, rspec - Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm running a feature spec to test some Rails code.   The spec runs fine however, there is some js that needs to be tested.

As per the documentation, I've added the :js => true flag to the scenario.  However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) User can check off items as being owned user can check off an item on the checklist
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     Errno::EADDRINUSE:
       Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:3000
     # /Users/agazoom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kollista/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:32:in `new'
     # /Users/agazoom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kollista/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:32:in `run'
     # /Users/agazoom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kollista/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:173:in `run_default_server'
     # /Users/agazoom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kollista/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:359:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/agazoom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kollista/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/server.rb:70:in `call'
     # /Users/agazoom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@kollista/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/server.rb:70:in `block in boot'
```

The test is listed below.   This is strange because the thing runs fine when I remove the js flag:

```
scenario "user can check off an item on the checklist", :js => true do
   visit root_path
   expect(page).to have_title("agazoom")
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I did some experimenting and discovered that when I turn off webkit, the tests work.   Basically, it looks like Capybara was trying to use the same port as webkit and failing when using js.  Don't ask me the details as to why or how.

So, I just changed the port on which Capybara runs in 'rails_helper':

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  .
  .
  config.server_port = 3001
end
```